# multiple repeat error in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying some regexes in python

```
re.compile('in versions: (.+?) of '+name+' ')
```

and, if name is 'libcrypto++', cause **multiple repeat error**

how can i handle it only in a string..?

Comment: use `re.escape(name)` since it contains `+` characters which have otherwise special meaning in the context of regular expressions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`+` is a quantifier in regex. So when you add `libcrypto++` to regex string, it brings two of them alongside that doesn't make sense.
See [this.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers)

To solve this you can use regex [escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) method, like:

```
re.compile('in versions: (.+?) of '+ re.escape(name) +' ')
```